# Faced with Changing Hamburger Button to Home Button

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar, android-homebutton

I faced with a problem. I have MainActivity with Fragment1 and Navigation Drawer. There is a button  in Fragment1 that replace Fragment1 and Fragment2. When Im replacing, I want to turn off Navigation Drawer, change Hamburger button to Home button("<"). So I have method changeTbOn in MainActivity and call it in onCreate Fragment2:

```
((MainActivity)getActivity()).changeTbOn();
```

My changeTbOn method:

```
public void changeTbOn(){
       toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
        toggle.syncState();
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
       drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
```

When I did it, Navigation Drawer turn off, Hamburger button didnt changes to Home Button, but it works like Home Button. What I do wrong? I want change it to Home Button icon. Help Please!

Comment: Add `getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.your_home_icon);` I don't know if this is the solution, or the only solution even if it is, mostly just interested if it "fixes" it. I also think there is a `setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);` method

Comment: Now I have Hamburger Button and near my home icon, but I need change HamubrgerButton to home icon..

Comment: Hide your hamburger button and show your home button. They are two different icons and have two different behaviors.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**: 
Add this to my `changeTbOn` method:

```
 toggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.back_icon);
```